# Connect to the Internet without permission

Tags: android, permissions, connection

How can you update data with Internet connection, but without any permission, like in this android app?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.youcorp.matchschedule.eu 
 http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot2014ty0vjlxsu7.png

Comment: Maybe you write something, why you give negative vote for my question, without even having tested it. Just becasuse you super-all-knowing-programmer believe, that something is impossible, it doesn't have to be impossible.

Comment: No, you cannot access internet without the network permission

Comment: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot2014ty0vjlxsu7.png

Comment: Why are you so opposed to simply adding the permission?

Comment: I wanted to know how it can be, that an application is shown as "no permission needed", although it obviously needs a permission. Because the point is, if there are other permissions, that are handled like the internet-connection permission, I would like to know this. And that is important for me as user as well as developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` in the Manifest file. There's no way around it. But as of the latest Play Store update (4.8.19), the Internet Permission won't show up on the dialog. That's why the text says *"does not require **any special permissions**"*.

Google also states this in the following Support document ([Click](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en))
*"These days, apps typically access the Internet, so network communication permissions including the “full Internet access” permission have been moved out of the primary permissions screen."*

Comment: It's very concerning that Google doesn't explicitly specify "Internet Access" in the permissions anymore (I only found something more general under permissions "Other" for that app referenced just as "full network access"), especially since I wanted to try an NFC card reader app to see what my chipped credit cards actually broadcast, and it didn't explicitly say anything about internet access either (and the Play store app and browser page have slightly different views for those boxes). Banking card reader NFC (EMV): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.devnied.emvnfccard

Answer (score -1):

That app you are linking to has full network permissions.

Comment: No, when I installed it, google showed that there are no permissions needed for this app.

Comment: If you click on the link you provided, and expand the "permission link" it shows that it requires full network access

Comment: If you click the link in a standard browser it says that it needs full network access

Comment: Here the Screenshot from a directlink in browser... It still shows, that no permission is required. http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot2014v1ux03p6sk.png

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1l1CuiShumBMjFYRGpyWGFFMU0/edit?usp=sharing It has Network permissions.. In the other categories