# How to send data to the internet without android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, network-connection

The description of the full network access permission states:

> Network communication
>   Allows the app to create network sockets and use custom network protocols.
>   The browser and other applications provide means to send data to the
>   internet, so **this permission is not required to send data to the
>   internet.**

I checked already the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633963/how-can-i-send-post-data-from-android-to-php-without-using-internet-permission) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228111/connect-to-the-internet-without-permission) but it looks like they are not considering this description.

What are the possible ways (besides sending intent to browser) to send data to the internet without using android.permission.INTERNET?
What do Google employees mean with this description?

Comment: Why don't you want to use it in the manifest? Trying not to use it may give you a SecurityException.

Comment: where is that quote coming from

Comment: @TimCastelijns If you open the permissions of an installed application that uses internet permission, you can click on `full network access` or whatever it is for your version of Android OS and it will show the above quote.

Comment: It simple means, What ever you do it will save offline when their is no network and once internet will avail it will send all data to network.

Comment: why is this a problem anyway? Almost all apps have this permission, and users don't care

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want to explore more ways to achieve the same goal and if there is a more appropriate solution for a given use-case I prefer to use that instead of the default solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think they mean that you can create an implicit intent to other applications that have network capabilities (e.g. browsers, other app that connects to the internet) and this way you could send data but with the inherent constraints.

That description is taken from the `android.permission.INTERNET` definition.

**EDIT**

An example would be a text message sent via an implicit intent. It could be sent via whatsapp or other internet messaging service without requiring the permission you mentioned.